# edit information given within a form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, edit

Hello everyone I wish I could change a value in a form by recovering the original one, to simply change the value and to change in the database
I'm trying to edit a Modelform with an "edit" button but the form isn't updated.
The instantiation of the original values is not done
So i have a

> models.py

```
class Champs(models.Model):
    champs = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contenu = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.contenu) > 17:
            return self.champs[:16] + "..."
        else:
            return self.champs
```

> forms.py

```
class ChampsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Champs
        fields = ('champs','contenu')
```

> Views.py

```
    def champs(request):
        logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
        champs = Champs.objects.all()
        if logged_user:
            if len(request.GET) > 0:
                form = ChampsForm(request.GET)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save(commit=True)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/champs')
                else:
                    return render_to_response('polls/champs.html', {'champs': champs, 'form': form})
            else:
                form = ChampsForm()
                return render_to_response('polls/champs.html', {'champs': champs, 'form': form})
        else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')

    def modify_champs(request):

        if logged_user:
            if len(request.GET) > 0:
                form = ChampsForm(request.GET, instance=...)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save(commit=True)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/champs', {'user_to_show':logged_user})
                else:
                    return render_to_response('polls/modify_champs.html', {'form': form, 'instance':...})
            else:
                form = ChampsForm(instance=...)
                return render_to_response('polls/modify_champs.html', {'form': form, 'instance':...})
        else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
```

> The template for champs.py -->

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
        <h1>Formulaire</h1>
        <form action="" method="GET" >{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" id="showProfileNavigationButtons" />
                </p>

        <table>
        {% for champs in champs %}<hr>
            (Son id :) {{ champs.id }}<br><br>{{ champs.champs }} : {{ champs.contenu }}
            <a href="../modifyChamps">Modifier</a>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>

        </form>
 </div>
```

> And for finish the template for modify_champs -->

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
        <h1>Formulaire</h1>
        <form action="" method="GET" >{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" id="showProfileNavigationButtons" />
                </p>

        </form>
```

- **I want to retrieve information listed in my form in the template "champs.html" and find them in the form "modify_champs.html" and be
  able to change them! Thanks you for your times !**
  [image: the template champs.html]

Comment: Forms shouldn't really use `get` at all` their data should be `POST`ed, hence why you've included a csrf token already

Comment: I think this is not the problem because the first forms return me good i go share a screen

Comment: Someone have an idea ?

Comment: I think ijames55 was correct but they have now deleted their answer, your new url (modifyChamps) has no knowledge of the model instance that its trying to edit, you need to construct a url that will allow you to open up a form on an instance

Comment: Do you have an exemple ? please

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/modifyChamps/(?P%3Cinstance%3E[0-9]+)/                   I have a page not found ... :S

Answer (score 0):

Set the modify_champys url in urls.py to something like `url(r'^modify_champs/(?P<instance>[0-9]+)/$',.....)`.

Then change the view declaration in views.py to `def modify_champs(request, instance):`.

Inside the views.py change `form = ChampsForm(request.GET, instance=...)` to `form = ChampsForm(request.GET, instance=Champs.objects.get(pk=instance)`.

Then when you change the URL to `http://.../modify_champs/1` the form will select the Champs object with the primary key 1.

Then you just need to use HTML or javascript to link to the relevant URL.

EDIT: I assumed this was a POST request not GET so this might be incorrect